# How to architect a web-based, 3D product designer using Blender?

Tags: python, django, web, 3d, blender

So I'm trying to create a 3D web product designer similar to:

Zazzle's Custom iPhone Builder: 
http://www.zazzle.com/case_mate_iphone_5_5s_vibe_case_iphone_5_5s_case-179139058105217167

ShoesOfPrey: https://www.shoesofprey.com/3d/designer?p=20600P4

It seems that the 3D modeling (skinning, colors, etc) is done server side, with jpeg snapshots taken at a few angles and passed to the client. I have a blender script that does this on my computer, but I'm not sure what rendering engine they are running or how they are hosting it.

I would like to re-create this functionality exactly with other custom products (mugs, clothing, etc). I'm not worried about the front end design tools nor editing the 3D model with user inputs. I plan on using Django and Blender + python scripts to spit out images.

I want to know how to properly architect this app to get a working Version 1 prototype. I'm familiar with Django and front-end design tools, but have little to no experience with networking, hosting, scaling, setting up workers, load balancing, task queuing, passing data from render farm to django, etc.

That might be a bit too open ended, so I'll try to be more specific. Apologies for the noobness:

**Question 1:** What's a good hosting service for blender that lets me run the python scripts?

**Question 2:** Would Celery come in handy anywhere here? Not too sure about what it does or why it's important.

**Question 3:** Ideally, I'd like users to see a resulting image in <=1 second (doesn't have to be as fast as the examples). The app would need to handle maybe 100 simultaneous users at a time. Would I need a render farm, or can any server running python handle this load?

If there's anything I'm overlooking, please let me know! This is also my first stackoverflow post, and I'm a little disappointed in myself that it is a vague question without any code :(.

**EDIT-- Question 4:** A possible tech stack suggestion (Django + Blender + ???) that could be used to make a project like this would be helpful in getting me off the ground and looking into the right places for answers.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of latency you can expect from Blender's builtin network rendering, so you'll have to compare it with using a bunch of Celery workers that run `blender` via the command line. Celery works across multiple machines, so you can just spin up new worker nodes if the load is too high. Your questions don't really have one specific answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response and clarity on how Celery can be used here! I'm just trying to understand the interconnecting parts as much as possible since I'm new to a lot of the backend work here, so unspecific responses are still helpful. I'd like to have an idea of a tech stack (using Django + Blender + unknown rendering server + unknown other components) needed for a project like this

Comment: maybe have a look at Blend4web if you want something real cool 3d on the web.